# How to change the bootstrap carousel indicators and controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I stuck am trying to be able to change the location of bootstrap carousel indicators and controls. Looking like something like this carousel at this website. http://www.mitre10.co.nz/ Were the indicators and controls are at bottom and away from the image.

Here is my live view http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/qdiup

```
<header id="masterhead">
<div class="container">  
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="slideshow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">   
            <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://s20.postimg.org/wgz1zd3wd/slide1.jpg" alt="slide"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
          <img src="http://s20.postimg.org/l3cio5tdp/slide2.jpg" alt="slide"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s20.postimg.org/w0ducxg59/slide3.jpg" alt="slide"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s20.postimg.org/lrld73s3h/slide4.jpg" alt="slide"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slideshow" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slideshow" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
</div>

</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't open your example site, but you can move those indicators out of their current spot and place them where you wish. I moved them out of the header in your CodePen, wrapped them in a container and added some styles to move them below your images and center them:

```
<div class="carousel-controls">
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slideshow" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">   
        <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#slideshow" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slideshow" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-controls{
 position:relative; 
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.carousel-indicators{
   top:0px; 
}
```

ref: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tayfk/

Comment: how do you also make the carousel-control to go either side of the carousel-indicators like <oooo>

Comment: Now there is another  problem, the indicators are not showing the active slide. It just stay on first indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a template for a carousel, with positionable controls, and a progress navbar at the bottom that tracks the slides.

http://codepen.io/TheNickelDime/

```
<!-- HTML -->

    <div class="Slideshow_carousel-wrapper container-fluid">
        <span class="Slideshow-ctl-L" onclick="carousel_left()"></span>
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  ... </div>    
        <span class="Slideshow-ctl-R" onclick="carousel_right()"></span>

    </div>

<!-- /HTML -->

<!-- CSS -->

.Slideshow_carousel-wrapper {

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:         flex;


    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    text-align:center;

    width:100%; 
}



/* SLIDESHOW CONTROLS LEFT / RIGHT */
.Slideshow-ctl-L {

    -webkit-flex: none;
     flex: none;

    z-index:200;

    top:40%;
    margin-right:5px;

    height:60px;
    width:16px;

    opacity:0.7;

    background-size:15px 60px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url( ... );
}



.Slideshow-ctl-R {

    -webkit-flex: none;
     flex: none;


    top:40%;
    margin-left:5px;

    height:60px;
    width:15px;


    opacity:0.7;

    background-size:15px 60px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url( ... );
}

<!-- CSS -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit bootstrap.js to have multiple classes recognized as indicators.

```
var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators, .your-class-here')
```

Comment: It's bad idea to make changes in 3rd party library. These changes will make upgrade harder.

Comment: You can use this JS code , it will do what you need
....

`$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $(".carousel-indicators2 li").removeClass("active");
  indicators = $(".carousel-indicators li.active").data("slide-to");
  a = $(".carousel-indicators2").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicators + "']").addClass("active");
  console.log(indicators);
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JS Code to have multiple classes recognized as indicators.  **"the new indicators will showing the active slide and adding class active to indicator"**

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
$(".carousel-indicators2 li").removeClass("active");
indicators = $(".carousel-indicators li.active").data("slide-to");
a = $(".carousel-indicators2").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicators + 
"']").addClass("active");
console.log(indicators); <!-- You can remove this line "This line makes you see the active indicator in the console in the browser" -->
```

})